# Oracle Varchar2 to SQL Server Varchar

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, varchar, varchar2

These are my column definitions:

```
Oracle: Varchar2(128 byte)
Sql Server: Varchar(20)
```

These should be compatible.
When I map columns in SSIS (I need to migrate data from Oracle to SQL Server), it says:

> cannot convert from unicode to non-unicode

Any suggestions?

Comment: The Oracle database can use a character set capable of storing Unicode in a `VARCHAR2` (like UTF-8) and multibyte character sets that are not compatible with any collation of SQL Server. The safe type to convert to is `NVARCHAR(128)`.

Comment: your column in SQL Server needs to be `NVARCHAR`

Comment: Is Varchar2(128 byte) means that I can insert there a string, built from 64-unicode chars (each one 2 bytes)?